# Solving Integral with Symbolic Computation (Sympy), Division and Tricky Limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, symbolic-computation

A physics teacher on an online course [presented](https://youtu.be/pJwg2Bk0BDE?t=1286) this integral,

$$ 
= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Q x}{L} 
\int _{-L/2}^{L/2} \left(\frac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \right) \hat{x}
$$

and said she solved it with Wolfram Alpha, which gave

$$
= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{x \sqrt{x^2 + (L/2)^2}}\hat{x}
$$

I was wondering how to solve this using any other symbolic software like Sympy. I tried this for the indefinite integral,

```
from sympy import integrate, sqrt, Symbol, pprint
y = Symbol('y')
x = Symbol('x')
print (integrate('1/ ((x**2+y**2)**(3/2))',y))
```

Result is

```
y/(x**3*sqrt(1 + y**2/x**2))
```

I plugged in the limits,

```
from sympy import simplify
L = Symbol('L')
x = Symbol('x')
simplify((L/2)/(x**3*sqrt(1 + (L/2)**2/x**2)) - \
         (-L/2)/(x**3*sqrt(1 + (-L/2)**2/x**2)))
```

I get

```
2*L/(x**3*sqrt(L**2/x**2 + 4))
```

which does not look right. Does anyone have any experience solving integrals such as the one above using symbolic software?

Comment: You should apply the limits to the expression you obtained. Then you get the same answer as the teacher, unless you missed some factors

Comment: The indefinite integral can be checked by differentiation: $$d/dy (y/ \sqrt{x^2+y^2})=1/ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-y^2/(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}=x^2/(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}$$

Comment: Please edit the question with the end result after plugging in the limits. Also please use MathJax for all the formulas

Comment: I just evaluated the limits. Also, my question is mainly on the symbolic computation; that's why sympy output had to be included.

Comment: You reset a=Symbol('x') after setting it to Symbol('a'). Shouldn't that be x=Symbol('x')?

Comment: Great catch! Just corrected the output.

Comment: No I substitue L/2 and -L/2. Actually I realized what I missed - I did the symbolic integral, but there is an L and x outside, which cancels out one L and multiplies an x. So ```2*L/(x**3*sqrt(L**2/x**2 + 4))``` becomes ```2*x/(x**3*sqrt(L**2/x**2 + 4))```. When I plug in sample values into this and lecture result, they give same result. Lecture output (Wolfram Alfa) looks cleaner though.